# Mathematica file transforms to some strange format

Tags: format

I am facing a very annoying problem with mathematica file. Sometimes it is automatically saved in a "pdf like" bizarre format. Each input and output line of the original (.nb) file starts with In[#] and Out[#] respectively. Here is how it looks. [image]

I can not transform into usual input type format. I have to re-type the whole file again! :( I've no idea what's going on here.

EDIT :

Here is the link to the file : https://www.dropbox.com/s/b71d14rlkf9vcx4/scalar-w4.nb?dl=0

Info : I use mathematica 10.0 and I just realized this is happening in my desktop which is debian 7.8 (64 bit). But it also happens in my laptop (ubuntu 14.04) if I try to modify that file.

Comment: Would you be able to provide some more details that might allow others to reproduce your problem? Let's start with OS, MMA version, any behavioral patterns you might have observed...

Comment: @MarcoB I use ubuntu 14.04.  It happens very randomly. I am always scared to save any .nb file now!

Comment: This seems a very random occurrence; unless somebody else has experience this, it would seem to me that you need to get in touch with WRI support for troubleshooting. Anyway, when you open one of these garbled files back in *Mathematica*, does it still contain selectable text? If so, at the very least you should be able to remove the `In` and `Out` expressions with some text manipulation tool, and avoid having to retype your notebook.

Comment: Do you have a place where you can put one of the changed files online?

Comment: @MarcoB that's exactly what I am doing. But it's still annoying and it happens again and again!

Comment: @rcollyer can I upload the file here or mail somewhere? I have no idea.

Comment: try dropbox, or someplace like that.

Comment: @rcollyer I can upload it to dropbox but who do I share it to? If I was given some mail ID I would send it to there.

Comment: Create a link to it using the dropbox website, and post it here.

Comment: Once uploaded to Dropbox you can get a direct link to your file by going to "share" ( or sth. similar, I don't know the exact term in English interface) and instead of inviting you have an option to copy a download link

Comment: Added the link to the file. Hopefully it will work..

Comment: worked. Will look at it later. My first impression: weird.

Comment: Every time I have a problem that seems completely inexplicable I try this first - http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464

Comment: @N.J.Evans Tried that as well. Didn't work. :(

Comment: The format of the file you shared is reminiscent of what you would get if you "Save As..."  -> "Plain Text", but I assume that you did not select plain text format when you saved. It may we worth checking, however, whether for some reason your "Save..." mistakenly defaults to Plain Text format for some reason.

Comment: @MarcoB I had the same doubt for the first few ocassions. But then I realized it's very random and not due to  "Save As..." -> "plain text".

Comment: Sorry, I just realized this is happening only in my desktop which is debian 7.8 (64 bit).  But it also happens in my laptop (ubuntu 14.04)  if I try to modify that file. May be I should add this info..

Comment: Does this happen when using only **Save** or only **Save as...**?  If it does not affect both commands we might learn something from that.

Comment: *" if I try to modify that file."* -- just to be sure, you're not editing these Notebook files outside of *Mathematica*, or opening the same Notebook in two different *Mathematica* sessions, are you?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I have tried both of them. Result is same!

Comment: When this problem occurs do you know right away or only when you reload the Notebook?  I mean does the content of the Notebook, still open, suddenly change when you get a "bad" save?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I realize when I open the saved Note book again. 
And I thought that might be the cause, that's why I always open files from single session.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard On Linux, Mathematica launches a new instance of the front end every time you open a notebook.  It's very easy to open the same file in two different instances of Mathematica.

Answer (score 2):

Opening the file in emacs shows that it is a text file in UTF-8.  The Greek characters display correctly.  My emacs setup doesn't have the Wolfram private use character font installed, so the double struck differential [DifferentialD] doesn't display properly.  A Chinese character is displayed.  But it is a text file, without doubt.

```
          position: 12423 of 12449 (100%), column: 14
        character:  (displayed as ) (codepoint 63308, #o173514, #xf74c)
preferred charset: unicode (Unicode (ISO10646))
code point in charset: 0xF74C
           syntax: w    which means: word
         category: L:Left-to-right (strong), c:Chinese
         to input: type "C-x 8 RET f74c"
      buffer code: #xEF #x9D #x8C
        file code: #xEF #x9D #x8C (encoded by coding system utf-8-unix)
          display: by this font (glyph code)
xft:-FYNN-Jomolhari-normal-normal-normal-*-15-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1 (#x51A)

Character code properties: customize what to show
general-category: Co (Other, Private Use)
decomposition: (63308) ('')
```